# Javascript 'undefined is not a function' - can you clarify this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

*The relevant HTML:*

```
<div id="suggestedEmailDiv">  
  Did you mean <a class="suggestedEmailClass">
    <span id="suggestedEmailAddressSpan" class="address"></span>
    @
    <span id="suggestedEmailDomainSpan" class="domain"></span>
  </a>?
</div>
```

**The relevant javascript:**

```
console.log("suggestion.address ", suggestion.address);
console.log("suggestedEmailAddressSpan ", $('suggestedEmailAddressSpan'));
// here's where it goes wonky:
$('suggestedEmailAddressSpan').text(suggestion.address);
```

**The relevant Logs:**

```
[Log] suggestion.address  qwew (btadmin, line 195)  <-- suggestion.address has a value
[Log] suggestedEmailAddressSpan   (btadmin, line 198) <-- it is a defined span!!
<span id=​"suggestedEmailAddressSpan" class=​"address">​</span>​

[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$('suggestedEmailAddressSpan').text(suggestion.address)')
suggested (btadmin, line 205)
responder (prototype.js, line 5597)
```

I know I am missing something simple but important here...  What is it??

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: you have to use $('#suggestedEmailAddressSpan').text(suggestion.address);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the closest thing I can think of is that **jQuery is not loaded**.

What gave it away is that your log didn't return a jQuery object. jQuery returns an array-like object, which on the console appears like a bracketed list of elements. You can verify this by doing `$('body')` on the console in this StackOverflow page (because SO uses jQuery :P) and you should see something like:

```
[<body class=​"question-page new-topbar">​…​</body>​]
```

Now two things may have resulted when jQuery is not loaded:

- `$` is `undefined`, resulting in that error.
- Some browsers (like [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#selector)) natively have a `$` function which maps to [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector). If jQuery didn't load, the `$` global wasn't overridden. The error is because you called `text()` on the result of `querySelector`, which is the first DOM element that matches the provided selector.

Another possible situation is that something else has taken over the `$` global. Symptoms may include jQuery successfully loaded but `$` isn't jQuery. But your logs don't give much clues if this happened.

To solve your problem, make sure jQuery is loaded before your script. In addition, place scripts that operate on the DOM inside a callback to `$(document).ready()`, that way your scripts operate after the DOM has fully loaded.

---

In addition, your selector is wrong. ID's selectors start with `#`. ***However***, providing wrong selectors to jQuery should not make the error since calling a wrong selector will return an empty jQuery set that  will still have the `.text()` method.

Comment: I have this in the header:    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @SteveCronin Judging by your log, jQuery didn't load at all. jQuery returns an array-like object, not a DOM element. Check the network panel of your debugger to see if jQuery did load.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  It was a jQuery config issue.  In the course of debugging this I came up with this snipppet...  Just drop it at the top of the first <script> block: <br> jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){ 
    console.log('Hello World! jQuery v: ', $.fn.jquery);        
    $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
}

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the id selector in your query it should be like this 
`$("#suggestedEmailAddressSpan")` read more about [JQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/?s=selector)

Comment: Here's what happens then: [Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '$('#suggestedEmailAddressSpan').text')

Comment: did you wait the window load event or you are executing code before that ?

Comment: to check to see if JQuery is loaded just log this to the console before the line of code that cuased your error `typeof jQuery` if you get anything than undefined then it's loaded

Answer (score 0):

for selecting Ids use

```
$('#suggestedEmailAddressSpan')
```

for class use

```
$('.suggestedEmailClass')
```

for jquery it's better to write your codes between ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //your code
});
```